# Jquery and/or Javascript Condition Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display region and city if is available and display the country text if city is not available. I tried adding if else condition and setup the variable but it returns blank, undefined or nulled. On the header I have the script below

```
jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
    jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
    jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);  


  }


} );
 var mycountry = document.getElementById("country-name").value;
 var mycity = document.getElementById("country-name").value;
 var myregion = document.getElementById("city").value;
```

then on the body I have

```
if (mycity !=  "") {    
document.write(mycity); document.write(myregion);  }    
else     {
document.write(mycountry);    
}
```

and the result I got is nulled or undefined.

reference
http://pastebin.com/xaqq16Ks

Comment: first did you check if the data returned from the ajax request is defined?

Comment: `if(mycity !=  "")` may fail if it's undefined though, better way would be to revert condition by `if(mycity)`

Comment: he's simply using ajax with `document.write`.

Comment: I mean the check in body is running synchronously while ajax is async. `document.write` will of course output null.

Comment: if id do <span id="city"> it would display without issue , the problem is I am trying to create a condition how to display those city and country

Answer (score 0):

*AJAX* is an async operation. You can't use `document.write` with *AJAX*. Add the `if (city === '')` logic to success callback instead.

Comment: can you provide reference or sample? thanks I am not sure what add the "check" means

Comment: so `$.ajax` will call the `success` function after a few seconds. not instantly. You can't put `if (mycity !=  "") {` in body because it will run before ajax has finished loading. Just move that part, including `var mycountry...` to the `success` function.

Comment: This dipends on how you have your code organized in your script. So we can not see how and where your file are located. So this could be caused by many factors. Please post some relevant code so we can follow the script execution.

Comment: yeah, which brings another issue. is `#country-name` a `div` or an `input`? You use `.html()` somewhere and `.value` in another place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display them in text fields, then you should change value instead of html:

```
$('#city').val(location.city);
$('#region-name').val(location.region_name);
$('#country-name').val(location.country_name);
```

and the rest of the code will run just fine.

Otherwise if you want to display them with a span/div or any other element, use should change the second part of your code, namely, you should get the innerHTML property and not value as follows:

```
 var mycountry = document.getElementById("country-name").innerHTML;
 var mycity = document.getElementById("city").innerHTML;
 var myregion = document.getElementById("region-name").innerHTML;
```

Comment: unless country-name is an input, and then he should use `jQuery('#country-name').val` instead

Comment: gets undefined document.write(mycountry);

Comment: the answer was fixed. but you should also pay attention that in your original code country-name element value is assigned to both mycountry and mycity.

Comment: ofcourse it will not work, Ajax call is an async operation. javascript first executes all synced operations and then the asynced. That's why mycountry, mycity, myregion are undefined, because they're displayed before their html was set. Your if/else code should be moved inside the success function right when the data is available to the client side.